# How to divide each row of a cell array by another cell array?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm a beginner at Matlab and I need to solve a problem that seems to be easy.

I have two cell arrays of the same size; 'hh:mm' (Col1) and data (Col2). I need to make the division of each value in column 2 of cell array A by cell array B and create a new cell array with the results as follows:

```
Cell A= {'00:40', [5.5];'00:45', [10.0]}

Cell B= {'00:40',[2.25];'00:45', [5.0]};
```

The result is:

```
Cell C= {'00:40', [2.44]; '00:45', [2.0]}
```

I've already tried the cat and cellfun commands, but without sucess! I've data from 00:00 to 24:00 hours.

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%Copy first col
C=A(:,1)
%calculate second col
C(:,2)=cellfun(@rdivide,A(:,2),B(:,2),'UniformOutput',false)
```

The `'UniformOutput',false` causes `cellfun` to return a `cell`, otherwise a vector is returned.

Comment: I think you missed the `;` in the question. C is 2x2

Comment: Thanks guys!!! Both answers are sensational. Daniel R's answer is the easiest. Really need to change thewaywewalk' answer from C 1x1 to C 2x2. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Appeared one more doubt: Is there a way to subtract the 'hh:mm'(Col1) by 3 hours and put it in ascending order? E.g: '03:00'='00:00'... '00:40'='21:40'. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user3084312: Use `datenum` to convert to a numeric value. These can be sorted using `sort`. If you are unable to solve this on your own, please create a new question.

Comment: Ok Daniel R. Thanks again!

Comment: @thewaywewalk, I want to learn how your code works as cell array 2x2. How can I do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: @user3084312: I don't understand your question. Is it about the single code line thewaywewalk wrote in the comments, or do you have a question about the answer he deleted himself?

Comment: @user3084312 my code suggestion the comments was wrong. And my answer was the same like Daniel R's but with a loop and a little mistake.